# macro sustituir puntos por comas y mantener formatos VBA

Tags: vba

Tengo un problema y es que estoy usando replace para cambiar los puntos por comas de una hoja XXX pero (solo de una hoja activa) y me cambia el formato a texto, ¿sabéis cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: No hay ninguna forma de solucionar ese problema. Excel solo admite los números con la coma para diferenciar la parte decimal. No puedes hacer ninguna operación con ese valor, puesto a que al no reconocerlo como número, lo considera como texto.

Comment: No puede ser, si lo hago manualmente con la opción de reemplazar si me cambia el formato a numérico.

Comment: Puedes sumarle 1 a ese nuevo valor?

Comment: En VBA para cambiar el separador decimal puedes usar `application.DecimalSeparator`, pero afectará a todo el libro, no solo a la hoja.

Comment: @David_helo , si le sumo y afecta al resultado no podría. Además hay datos que tiran de esta hoja.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes ok, necesitaría que solo afectase a la hoja activa. gracias

Comment: No puedes. Es una limitación del propio programa. Lo único que quizás podría hacer sería combinarlo con el evento de cambio de hoja, de tal manera que cuando la hoja activa sea diferente a la que quieres, el separador decimal sea la coma, y cuando sea la hoja activa que tú quieres, el separador decimal sea el punto.